# How to plot loglog in R with errbar?

Tags: r

I want both x-axis and y-axis to be logarithmic.Here is what I have done so far

```
errbar(per2,rhoaxy,exi1,exi2, col='red', xlab='Per (s)', ylab = 'Rho-xy/yx')

> per2
 [1]  2.81360874  2.68867000  2.51257874  2.38764001  2.21154875  2.08661001
 [7]  1.91051875  1.78558009  1.60948876  1.48455009  1.30843101  1.18349220
[13]  1.00740123  0.88246226  0.70637106  0.58143227  0.40511865  0.28017986
[19]  0.10408848 -0.02085009
> rhoaxy
 [1]  13475.18  17658.74  24303.42  34104.41  62121.02  45718.47  96941.69
 [8]  69688.09 188165.80 122828.10 260874.30  93912.92 390809.20 134571.90
[15] 439696.10 110478.50 368654.60  67207.96 350241.50  82641.43
> exi1
 [1]   4472.281   5684.450  13169.390  11134.010  42598.020  24160.840
 [7]  73315.090  46995.290 150010.550  83811.010 216371.890  59285.730
[13] 324797.040  89886.970 362980.730  79761.930 311042.060  50741.910
[19] 300799.430  65296.290
> exi2
 [1]  22478.08  29633.03  35437.45  57074.81  81644.02  67276.10 120568.29
 [8]  92380.89 226321.05 161845.19 305376.71 128540.11 456821.36 179256.83
[15] 516411.47 141195.07 426267.14  83674.01 399683.57  99986.57
```

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/plot.default.html explains log with plot,but how should I adapt this for my problem?

Comment: @ZheyuanLi I have added all the datasets.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi No,I need MATLAB loglog in R.